# Equivalent of std::aligned_storage<> in C?

Tags: c++, c, alignment, c99

In C, is there a way to get over-aligned (i.e. more alignment than can be deduced from the type system) storage on the stack?

For variables in dynamically allocated memory we can always align manually if all else fails but what can be done for variables in automatically allocated memory?

I guess it's possible to use a `char[size + alignment - 1]` and then always use bit manipulation to access the variable but this seems a "bit" shadier than necessary (har har har ;)).

Comment: Did you try _Alignas specifier ?

Comment: @this oops, I should have mentioned, no C11, thanks

Comment: Why did you accept the other answer if C11 wasn't an option? :-(

Comment: @this I didn't pick it for `_Alignas` but for the suggestion in the last paragraph to use an extension since it's the only way to get arbitrary alignments that might not match an existing type. Even though it's non-standard it's the only available solution and it is widely supported. I was torn about the decision though, both answers are good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C2011, there are the [`_Alignas`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignas) and [`_Alignof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof) keywords, the header `<stdalign.h>` which makes their use slightly less ugly, and the type [`max_align_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t) (which is in `<stddef.h>`).  You can, for instance, write

```
double _Alignas(4*_Alignof(double)) dvector[16];
```

to request an array of 16 `double` quantities aligned to 4x the usual alignment for `double`, as might be necessary for use with CPU-specific vector instructions.  This is not guaranteed to work on all implementations, but if it doesn't work it's guaranteed to be a compile-time error.

Prior to C2011 there was no *standard* way to do this, but many compilers did have extensions with similar functionality, e.g. GCC's [`__attribute__ (aligned)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes) construct.

Answer (score 5):

Well unions come to mind.

```
union This
{
    int integer;
    align_type alignment;
} ;
```

There is no padding before members in unions. So if you declare an automatic variable `union This`, then it, and all of its members, should be aligned the same as is alignment of the member with the highest alignment.